# most common value from associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a slight problem. How do I take out from associative array the products that are repeated most often, and show those products on the page? 
This is what the base looks like.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in your database? Don't you think it would better if you just sort out your structures?

Comment: That's horrible!

Comment: Are you using a MySQL JSON type for that column, or is that just varchar?

Comment: I've watched some tutorial and did it like they had done it. But if you have some better suggestion as to how to get it done, I am more than willing to listen.

Comment: If you are following the JSON structure, then store the product ID, and loop through the products array and maintain the product ID count. It will cost the processor, so please follow the database normalization techniques.

Comment: Use normalization, then this might be a simple SQL query. Or write an algorithm in PHP, that way you only have to write PHP code, but not change your database layout. But you should figure out the start on your own

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question:

You will need to things: JSON Operators and Group functions.
*Review if you have the appropiate Mysql version*

Assuming you have 'products' table and 'product' column, Follow this example:

```
select product->"$[*].PRODUCT", count(*) from products 
group by product->"$[*].PRODUCT" order by count(*) desc
```

The first row is the most common. It works well if you have one element per row.

But you should consider to normalize your database as others comments